# simulating n matrix samples with plots

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a function that allows the user to pick a nxn matrix, populate it with a sample of 0s and 1s, look for TIC TAC TOE "wins" (all 1s or 0s in a row, col, or diag), and plot a graph of the probability of a winning solution just based on a random sample.  I want the user to be able to run as many simulations as they want.

I already have a code for creating individual matrices

```
ranmat = function(nrow,ncol){
matrix(sample(c(0,1),replace=T,size=nrow*ncol),nrow=nrow)
```

and I also have ideas on how to check for wins, but I do not know how to run the simulation *n* times.

Comment: Can yo add the code that checks for wins too?

Comment: An, welcome to stackoverflow by the way :-)

Comment: Sure...my code for checking for wins....function (game)
{
if(any(colSums(game)==3,colSums(game)==0,rowSums(game)==3,
rowSums(game)==0,sum(diag(game))==3,sum(diag(game))==0,
sum(diag(apply(game,2,rev)))==3,sum(diag(apply(game,2,rev)))==0))
{return("YUP")}
else{return("NOPE")}
}  ## the 'yup' and 'nope' are for if there are any winners

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a for-loop? There's many ways of doing what you want to do I think.

```
# 1st option: you might want to call your function n times:
# with l,k and n being integer values (n is the number of simulation)
for(i in 1:n) ranmat(nrow=k,ncol=l) 

# 2nd option: you tell your function how often you want to simulate:
ranmat = function(nrow,ncol,nsimult){
    for(i in 1:nsimult){
        # your simulations
    }
    return(result) # with result being an appropriate way to return the outcome of your simulations
}
ranmat(nrow=k,ncol=l,nsimult=n) #call to your function with k,l and n being integer values
```